# Guard no longer detecting file changes with Yosemite OSX 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I set up a clean install of Yosemite and can't get guard to detect whenever a file is changed.

My Environment:

```
guard (2.6.1)
guard-minitest (2.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 both have been testing
```

Here is the output from debugging:

```
tom@Toms-MBP:~/Sites/tick (master)$ LISTEN_GEM_DEBUGGING=2 bundle exec guard -d
I, [2014-10-27T15:34:53.417196 #1059]  INFO -- : Celluloid loglevel set to: 0
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Command execution: emacsclient --eval '1' 2> /dev/null || echo 'N/A'
15:34:53 - INFO - Guard is using TerminalTitle to send notifications.
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Command execution: hash stty
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Guard starts all plugins
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Hook :start_begin executed for Guard::Minitest
15:34:53 - INFO - Guard::Minitest 2.3.2 is running, with Minitest::Unit 4.7.5!
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Hook :start_end executed for Guard::Minitest
15:34:53 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/tom/Dropbox/Sites/tick'
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Command execution: sysctl -n hw.ncpu
D, [2014-10-27T15:34:53.517668 #1059] DEBUG -- : Adapter: considering TCP ...
D, [2014-10-27T15:34:53.517749 #1059] DEBUG -- : Adapter: considering polling ...
D, [2014-10-27T15:34:53.517776 #1059] DEBUG -- : Adapter: considering optimized backend...
I, [2014-10-27T15:34:53.587089 #1059]  INFO -- : Record.build(): 0.06837701797485352 seconds
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Command execution: stty -g 2>/dev/null
15:34:53 - DEBUG - Start interactor
[1] guard(main)>
```

I am not sure how to test the underlying listen gem, but seems like it has to be related.  I have confirmed that guard works correctly with polling (`bundle exec guard start --force-polling`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by moving the files out of Dropbox.  Once I saw this working, I knew that Dropbox was somehow causing the issue with the file system.  I resolved it by removing the folder and re-adding it through Dropbox and now everything is working as before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and only thanks to a warning issued by the LiveReload application I fixed it. 
Because the problem is not restrained to Dropbox and/or ruby on rails, I wanted to share what I did:

- Rename problematic folder (in my case containing the Guardfile)
- Create new folder with the old folders name
- Move files from old to new folder

Other solutions mentioned by LiveReload are:

> - rebooting the computer
> - checking the disk and repairing permissions via Disk Utility
> - adding the folder to Spotlight privacy list (the list of folders to not index), and then removing from it, effectively forcing a
>     reindexing
> - renaming the folder, and then possibly renaming it back
> - re-creating the folder and moving the old contents back into it

Read more: http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86239

This not only fixed my Guard problem, but also allowed `Compass watch` to run again.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add **rb-fsevent** gem ?

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rb-fsevent' if `uname` =~ /Darwin/
end
```

if you're using OS X, it will be used OS X FSEvents API.